# How to change url in browserview in electron and maintain size and position

Tags: electron

I am trying to change the URL in a browserview within a main window in electron via a button click from the main window.

In other words, I have an html file loaded within the mainWindow like this:

---

> mainWindow.webContents.loadFile('html/index.html')

---

I also have a browserView added properly initially and added the ability to set its position and resize like this:

---

> mainWindow.setBrowserView(view)

> view.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => view.setBounds({x: 100, y:100,width: widthVal, height: heightVal   }))

> view.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => view.setAutoResize({
> width: true,
> height: true,
> horizontal: true,
> vertical: false   }))

---

When the app first opens, everything works, and adjusting the size of the app properly updates the browserviews via auto resize.

Within this html file, I have a button, which I can properly loop back to my main.js and execute the method:

---

> browserview.webContents.loadURL("www.newwebpage.com").

---

This does indeed change the browserview's url and displays it within the browserview.

However, if after opening the app, the size of the app changes, e.g. maximized, the size and location of the browserview changes within the application.  This works properly before i click my button to change the URL.  however, after I click the button and load the new URL, the browswerview size reverts back to the original size when the app was first opened.

I cannot get the browswerView to maintain its size and position after the app is maximized (or just not its default size when opened).  I tried forcing it via the same mechanism I used to call the browserview in the first place e.g. did-finish-load and view.setBounds().  This didn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

You need to query for the current size of the browserView and force it to that size after loading the new webpage:

```js
const bounds = view.getBounds()
view.webContents.loadURL('https://www.newpage.com')

view.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => view.setBounds({
    x: bounds.x,
    y: bounds.y,
    width: bounds.width,
    height: bounds.height
}))

view.setAutoResize({
    width: true,
    height: true,
    horizontal: true,
    vertical: false
})
```